# unable to post id of selected dropdown to controller through knockout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, knockout.js

This is my Post function something like this:

```
function Post(data) {
var self = this;
data = data || {};
self.PostId = data.PostId;
self.Message = ko.observable(data.Message || "");
self.PostedBy = data.PostedBy || "";
self.NeighbourhoodId = data.id || "";
```

This is my simple function in knockout. Here at the last line u can see, **data: ko.toJson(post)**

```
  self.addPost = function () {
var post = new Post();
post.Message(self.newMessage());
return $.ajax({
    url: postApiUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: ko.toJSON(post)
})
 .done(function (result) {
   self.posts.splice(0, 0, new Post(result));
   self.newMessage('');
 })
 .fail(function () {
   error('unable to add post');
 });
 }
```

Now, along with this, i want to pass dropdown selected id something like this:

```
  data: { id: $("#Locations").val() }
```

Right now, i have tried using this:

```
 data:{post: ko.toJSON(post), id: $("#Locations").val() }
```

but in controller, post: ko.toJSon(post) is sending nothing however i am getting id of selected dropdown but not the message property of post parameter.
If i use this line:

```
 data: ko.toJSON(post)
```

then i can get every property of post parameter but then id is null so, how to deal with this.Plzz Plzz help me out.Debugger is showing nothing useful information.My Post Controller is:

```
   public JsonResult PostPost(Post post, int? id)
{
    post.PostedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
    post.NeighbourhoodId = id;        
        db.Posts.Add(post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var usr = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == post.PostedBy);
        var ret = new
        {
            Message = post.Message,
            PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
            NeighbourhoodId = post.NeighbourhoodId
        };
    return Json( ret,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
}
```

on my view page,this is the button on which click event i fired addPost function

```
  <input type="button" data-url="/Wall/SavePost" id="btnShare" value="Share" data-bind="click: addPost">
```

along with this, dropdown for sending id is something like this:

```
   @Html.DropDownList("Locations", ViewBag.NeighbourhoodId as SelectList, "Select a location")
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                     $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#btnShare").click(function () {
                    var locationSelected = $("#Locations").val();
                    var url = '@Url.Action("PostPost", "Post")';
                    $.post(url, { id: locationSelected },
                   function (data) {
                               });
                            });
                          });
                    </script>
```

Plzz someone help me out.I am not getting what to do from here.

Comment: Have you tried `data: ko.toJSON({ post: post, id: $("#Locations").val() })`?

Comment: @haim 770 as u said tried this now inserting two new rows in database, in first one message col is null and neighbourId is 1 but in second row succesfully inserting both message and id

Comment: You need to choose jQuery or Knockout to control your DOM. Using both is not going to work for you.

Comment: @duke Your addPost method seems to add a blank post, perhaps that is why you are getting two posts: `self.posts.splice(0, 0, new Post(result));`